# Hazelcast register different clusters with similar required member

Tags: hazelcast

I have two application clusters with 3 nodes in each (A and B). Both clusters have different cluster group name and password (for separating into different clusters) and **similar join** configuration:

`<tcp-ip enabled="true">
     <required-member>10.0.0.1</required-member>
     <members>10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3</members>
</tcp-ip>`

So here is the problem - after starting cluster A (it unites and works perfectly) non master members of cluster B fail to find master member of B, they just find master of A and complain on wrong group cluster name and password.

Is where any work around for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different ports.
In your config, it uses default port `5701` for another cluster group.
You can configure port in `hazelcast.xml` like

`<network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">6701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <required-member>10.0.0.1:6701</required-member>
                <members>10.0.0.2:6701,10.0.0.3:6701</members>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
    </network>`

Let me know if you have any questions.
Thank you